# ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous:

Tags: tensorflow, cardinality

I'm using a code from : https://github.com/TheoMoumiadis/HVAC-calc-with-NN
but I have this error :
ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous:
x sizes: 667
y sizes: 668
Make sure all arrays contain the same number of samples.

Could you help me  ? Should I make a shape but how ?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import tensorflow as tf
import keras
from keras import models
from keras import layers
from keras.utils import np_utils


dataset = pd.read_csv('C:/.../ENB2012_data.csv')

print(dataset)

X_train = dataset.iloc[0:667,1:9].values.astype('float32')
Y1_train = dataset.loc[0:667,'Y1'].values.astype('float32')
Y2_train = dataset.loc[0:667,'Y2'].values.astype('float32')

X_test = dataset.iloc[668:767,1:9].values.astype('float32')
Y1_test = dataset.loc[668:767,'Y1'].values.astype('float32')
Y2_test = dataset.loc[668:767,'Y2'].values.astype('float32')

mean = X_train.mean(axis=0)
X_train -= mean
std = X_train.std(axis=0)
X_train /= std

X_test -= mean
X_test /= std

def build_model():
    
    model =models.Sequential()
    
    model.add(layers.Dense(64, input_dim=X_train.shape[1], activation='relu'))
    
    model.add(layers.Dense(64,activation='relu'))
    
    model.add(layers.Dense(1))

    model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='mse', metrics=['mae'])
    return model

model = build_model()
model.fit(X_train, Y1_train, epochs=300, batch_size=10, verbose=0)
test_mse_score, test_mae_score = model.evaluate(X_test, Y1_test)
```

Comment: Be careful what you select with `iloc`, try changing to `dataset.ix[0:667,1:9].values.astype('float32')`. Edit: The link you gave also did like this, check again.

Comment: If i use dataset.ix and not dataset.iloc I have an AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'ix'. I use Python 3.7.9 and tensorflow 2.4.1, Keras 2.4.3

Comment: Or you can use this `X_train = dataset.iloc[0:668,1:9].values.astype('float32')` and `X_test = dataset.iloc[667:767,1:9].values.astype('float32')`

Comment: Perfect, thanks you !

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Frightera and @Antoine. For the benefit of community providing solution here.

Please refer working code as shown below

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import tensorflow as tf
import keras
from keras import models
from keras import layers
from keras.utils import np_utils

dataset = pd.read_csv('C:/.../ENB2012_data.csv')

#print(dataset)

X_train = dataset.iloc[0:668,1:9].values.astype('float32')
Y1_train = dataset.loc[0:667,'Y1'].values.astype('float32')
Y2_train = dataset.loc[0:667,'Y2'].values.astype('float32')

X_test = dataset.iloc[667:767,1:9].values.astype('float32')
Y1_test = dataset.loc[668:767,'Y1'].values.astype('float32')
Y2_test = dataset.loc[668:767,'Y2'].values.astype('float32')

mean = X_train.mean(axis=0)
X_train -= mean
std = X_train.std(axis=0)
X_train /= std

X_test -= mean
X_test /= std

def build_model():
    
    model =models.Sequential()
    
    model.add(layers.Dense(64, input_dim=X_train.shape[1], activation='relu'))
    
    model.add(layers.Dense(64,activation='relu'))
    
    model.add(layers.Dense(1))

    model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='mse', metrics=['mae'])
    return model

model = build_model()
model.fit(X_train, Y1_train, epochs=300, batch_size=10, verbose=0)
test_mse_score, test_mae_score = model.evaluate(X_test, Y1_test)
```

Output:

```
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: 283.6571 - mae: 13.5637
```